# How can I keep the same progress even after refreshing and opening the browser in the same device (in react)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, local-storage

[like this I want to keep the same progress even after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/837TC.png) and even after closing and opening the browser in the same device

Comment: If this is purely a front-end application, you might want to take a look at cookies. If you do have back-end code + database, you might want to look into making an API and communicate with that from your React front-end.